# AutoCompleteTextView in adapter not working

Tags: android, listview, autocompletetextview

I have a listview with rowlayout having autocompletextview and a delete icon. There is a plus btn in the main layout along with listview. When we click on the plus btn, a new rowlayout is dynamically added to listview. On clicking the delete icon, we can delete the rowlayout for that position. The autocompletetextview shows some suggestions (I used string array and ArrayAdapter for that inside my listview adapter) and when I select any one of those suggestions, it gets set to autocompletetextview. My problem is everytime I add/remove an item from listview, the value showing in the previous autocompletetextview gets removed such that it shows the first the string array

```js
// Row Layout

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center">

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/myEt"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/delImg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_delete"/>



</LinearLayout>
```

```css
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button openBtn;
    ArrayList<Model> listItems=new ArrayList<Model>();
    ContactsListAdapter adapter;
    int resource;
    NonScrollListView list;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        openBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.openBtn);

        list = (NonScrollListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        adapter = new ContactsListAdapter(this, resource, listItems);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        openBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                addItems();
            }
        });


    }

    public void addItems() {
        Model model = new Model();
        model.setCount(listItems.size()+1);
        listItems.add(model);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }




}
```

```html
public class ContactsListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Model> {

    private Context mContext;
    int resource;
    private ArrayList<Model> arrayList = new ArrayList<Model>();
    String[] fruits = {"Apple", "Banana", "Cherry", "Date", "Grape", "Kiwi", "Mango", "Pear"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    public ContactsListAdapter(Context mContext, int resource, ArrayList<Model> arrayList) {
        super(mContext, resource, arrayList);
        this.resource = resource;
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(mContext, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, fruits);

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return super.getCount();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, @NonNull final ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (v == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();

            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_item, parent, false);

            holder.myEt  = (AutoCompleteTextView)v.findViewById(R.id.myEt);
            holder.delImg = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.delImg);

            v.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        }

        holder.myEt.setThreshold(3);
        holder.myEt.setAdapter(adapter);

        final Model item = arrayList.get(position);

        holder.myEt.setText(item.getName());



        holder.myEt.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
                arrayList.get(position).setName(fruits[pos]);

            }
        });

        /*holder.myEt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                *//*item.setName(s.toString());
                notifyDataSetChanged();*//*

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {


            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                item.setName(s.toString());
                //notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });*/


        holder.delImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                arrayList.remove(position);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });



        return v;
    }

    class ViewHolder {

        AutoCompleteTextView myEt;
        ImageView delImg;
    }

}
```

.

Comment: why you are using weight in autotextview ?

Comment: @duggu To show the delete icon in the listview.

Comment: do you know how weight works in layout ?

Comment: Yes I know. But can you provide me with a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try return `arrayList.size()` in `getCount()` method.

```
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }
```

class `ViewHolder` is inner class of Adapter, put it inside `ContactsListAdapter` Class

Comment: class ViewHolder is inner class of Adapter, put it inside Adapter Class

Answer (score 0):

Since I got it resolved I'm sharing my answer. I changed the AutoCompleteTextView's setOnItemClickListener() method. The full code is below.

```html
public class ContactsListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Model> {

    private Context mContext;
    int resource;
    private ArrayList<Model> arrayList = new ArrayList<Model>();
    String[] fruits = {"Apple", "Banana", "Cherry", "Date", "Grape", "Kiwi", "Mango", "Pear"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    public ContactsListAdapter(Context mContext, int resource, ArrayList<Model> arrayList) {
        super(mContext, resource, arrayList);
        this.resource = resource;
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(mContext, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, fruits);

    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Model getItem(int position) {
        return arrayList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, @NonNull final ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (v == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();

            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_item, parent, false);

            holder.myEt  = (AutoCompleteTextView)v.findViewById(R.id.myEt);
            holder.delImg = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.delImg);

            v.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        }

        holder.myEt.setThreshold(3);
        holder.myEt.setAdapter(adapter);
        holder.myEt.setTag(position);

        final Model item = arrayList.get(position);

        holder.myEt.setText(item.getName());

        System.out.println("sammy_name: "+item.getName() + " position: "+position);



        holder.myEt.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
                String value = parent.getAdapter().getItem(pos).toString();
                Model model = getItem(position);

                if (model != null) {
                    //model.setName(fruits[pos]);
                    model.setName(value);
                }
                System.out.println("sammy_name1: "+item.getName());

            }
        });


        holder.delImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                arrayList.remove(position);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });



        return v;
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
        AutoCompleteTextView myEt;
        ImageView delImg;
    }

}
```